Having trouble storing collection metadata apart from using an external database
It looks like there is not a practical way to store some metadata for a collection, which is something I would like to do.
System properties are stored in the 'properties' field; unfortunately, Milvus does not support the Collection.get_properties function. Custom properties can be stored in a different field. Although it's a somewhat improvised solution, I could store the metadata in a "description" field.
It appears that the only reliable method for storing collection metadata is to use an external database.
Can anyone provide some insights on this? That would be so helpful!

In Java v2.4.2 or v2.3.8, you can add customized properties into a collection with alterCollection() with the following code:
    milvusClient.alterCollection(AlterCollectionParam.newBuilder()
            .withCollectionName(COLLECTION_NAME)
            .withProperty("my_prop", "prop_value")
            .build());
    R<DescribeCollectionResponse> resp = milvusClient.describeCollection(DescribeCollectionParam.newBuilder()
            .withCollectionName(COLLECTION_NAME)
            .build());
    List<KeyValuePair> pairs = resp.getData().getPropertiesList();
    for (KeyValuePair pair : pairs) {
        System.out.println(pair);
    }

